# Monty Hall Dilemma with conditional probability

Tags: conditional-probability, monty-hall

The initial probability of each door being the winner is 0.1 for door 1, 0.2 for door 2, 0.3 for door 3, and 0.4 for door 4. The
formula for solving each conditional probability involves an application of the general Bayesian formula: for example, substituting
A, B, C, and D for doors l–4, respectively, the conditional probability of A being the winner, when the contestant initially picks A
and the host opens doors b and d can be determined by the formula:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nYyto.png)

I woould like someone explain, step by step, how I can use the formula to achieve the result in yellow (sticking - conditional probability). I am doing something wrong.

Comment: Grinstead C.M., Snell J.L. Introduction to probability (free web draft, 1999), on pages 137-139.

Comment: My suggestion is until conditional probability becomes intuitive, draw graphs and go from bottom of the graph up based on the constraint.

Comment: Assume door A is guessed.  If A is the right door, what is the probability that doors B and C will be selected?  If D is the right door, you are guaranteed that doors B and C will be selected, since door A was guessed.